# What's the difference between (be to + infinitive) and (be about to + infinitive)?

Tags: grammar

In my book, both forms mentioned in the title have been defined as:

> **Be to + infinitive** is commonly used in news reports to talk about events that are likely to happen in the future:
>
> - Police officers **are to visit** every home in the area.
>
> We use **be about to + infinitive** mainly in conversation to say that
> something will (not) happen in the very near future:
>
> - We'**re about to eat**. Do you want to join  us?

The book doesn't explain the difference (I assume there's no difference when we say **something is likely to happen** and **something will happen**). Regardless of the different usage between **be to** is used in news reports and **be about to** is used in conversation, are those forms have different meaning? Or is it just the formality usage that differs them? Meaning **be+to** is used in formal situation?

The reason I'm confuse, because the book, in the previous unit(chapter) also says that **will** can be used to state that something is likely to happen. [E.g. It will rain]. That's why I'm confused between those definitions.

Comment: Look at the excerpt you've posted again. One describes things that may "happen in the future" and one describes things that will "happen in the **very near** future."

Comment: @Katy Thank you for your nice point Katy. However, I'm still confused. For instance, *My sister is __ visit me this week.* I think both sound OK to me? Or they don't?